# Where else can I find alternate login URL aside from $CFG->alternateloginurl

Tags: moodle, moodle-theme

I'm currently troubleshooting a login issue for a deployed Moodle. Login page uses an *alternate page* which I have managed to identify. The alternate page considers everything except successful login as invalid or expired login or password.
Since some correct login and password are also getting the same issue.I am trying to restore the Moodle instance to use its default login page but did not find any *$CFG->alternateloginurl* configuration set in *moodle.php*. Kindly please provide any pointers you can think of on where to look next to restore the login page.

PS: I've also searched within the active theme, and there has not been any code changes. Uses a variant of Moove

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rest assured that its a common issue

https://docs.moodle.org/401/en/Managing_authentication#Alternate_login_URL

There is an entry in the database

```
SELECT *
FROM mdl_config
WHERE name = 'alternateloginurl'
```

Note the value, just in case, then blank it out

```
UPDATE mdl_config
SET value = ''
WHERE name = 'alternateloginurl'
```

Then purge the cache to update Moodle

```
php admin/cli/purge_caches.php
```

When you do manage to log in, check which other authentication methods are active via

Site administration > Plugins > Authentication > Manage authentication

https://docs.moodle.org/401/en/Managing_authentication

The default methods are manual and email self registration

Although self registration is disabled by default in the settings on the same page (registerauth)